# Radical equation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Find all real values of x for which
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac{1}{4}$$
I tried expanding and simplifing terms, but everything becomes too complicated, and the question is meant to be done under 15 minutes.
Is there a quick way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiplying the denominators and numerators with $$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2}$$ and $$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+2}$$ we get
$$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
can you proceed?
now we write
$$\sqrt{x+2}=1/2+\sqrt{x-2}$$
after squaring and simplifying we obtain
$$\sqrt{x-2}=\frac{15}{4}$$ thus we get the solution
$$x=2+\left(\frac{15}{4}\right)^2$$

Comment: yes i have corrected the terms, sorry it was a typo

Comment: numerators not nominators . ;-)

Comment: There is a solution, as Roberts Z. Shiws shows.

Comment: Actually, simplifying gets you $$\sqrt{x-2}=+ \frac{15}{4}$$ whose solution is $16+ \frac{1}{16}$

Comment: yes i have corrected my post the error was the minus sign

Comment: yes i have noticed it

Comment: I don't agree. Your last equation $\sqrt{x+2}=1/2+\sqrt{x-2}$ has solution $x=257/16$.